# error could not find or load main class (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, java

I have downloaded `jre1.8` on top of `jre1.6`. After downloading the `jre8` when I run a java program it shows the error `could not load main class`. What can I do?

Comment: Try removing all java installations and re-install only the latest.

Comment: I tried it is not working

Comment: After removing jre6 my jdk is not downloading